# Multiple file_put_contents with with str_replace?

Tags: php

I am trying to replace multiple parts of a string in a file with `file_put_contents`.
Essentially what the function does is finds a particular phrase in the file (which are in the `$new` and `$old` arrays and replaces it.

```
$file_path = "hello.txt";
$file_string = file_get_contents($file_path);
function replace_string_in_file($replace_old, $replace_new) {
    global $file_string; global $file_path;
    if(is_array($replace_old)) {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($replace_old); $i++) {
            $replace = str_replace($replace_old[$i], $replace_new[$i], $file_string);
            file_put_contents($file_path, $replace); // overwrite
        }
    }
}
$old = array("hello8", "hello9"); // what to look for
$new = array("hello0", "hello3"); // what to replace with
replace_string_in_file($old, $new);
```

hello.txt is: `hello8 hello1 hello2 hello9`

Unfortunately it outputs: `hello8 hello1 hello2 hello3`

So it outputs only 1 change when it should have outputted 2:
`hello0 hello1 hello2 hello3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a single file, so why output it after every replacement? Your workflow should be

```
a) read in file
b) do all replacements
c) write out modified file
```

In other words, move your file_put_contents() to OUTSIDE your loop.

As well, str_replace will accept arrays for its "todo" and "replacewith" arrays. There's no need to loop over your inputs. so basically you should have

```
$old = array(...);
$new = array(...);

$text = file_get_contents(...);
$modified = str_replace($old, $new, $text);
file_put_contents($modified, ....);
```

Your main problem is that your str_replace, as you wrote it, is never using the updated string. You constantly use the same ORIGINAL string for each replacement,

```
$replace = str_replace($replace_old[$i], $replace_new[$i], $file_string); 
                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^---should be $replace
```

Comment: Note: Your params for file_put_contents() are backwards, it's filename first.

Comment: woops, this was just an example, in my real code it's correct. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: It worked! Thank you, I used the str_replace with the arrays. I learned a lot of things in one post!

Answer (score 0):

You're not updating $file_string with each iteration. I.e., you set it once at the start of the loop, replace the first pair, and then the second call to replace uses the original $file_string again.

Comment: Note: I don't recommend you continue to do it this way (Marc's answer is great) -- was just pointing out the issue.